# Unreadable encoding of a SMB/Browser packet in Scapy

Tags: python, packet, scapy, smb, netbios

I'm trying to parse a pcap file with scapy (in python), and getting raw data at the layer above TCP.
on wireshark, all the layers are shown correctly:
[image: wireshark]

but on scapy all i'm seeing is just a Raw layer...
[image]

i'm thinking maybe it didn't parsed the packet well?
maybe the NetBIOS moduled did not load? or maybe i didn't import the module right? 
(i tryied:
 import scapy.all, import scapy, import scapy.layers.smb )
how do i make scapy load the layers of the packet correctly?

thanks!

Comment: Can you show us your code and possibly packet data?

Comment: hey! i just sniffed some traffic from my home network, the code at the python interpreter was just creating a PcapReader with the pcap file, and showing it's first packet...

Comment: @ToMeRh Did you found a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If someone has a similar problem…
You need something like
`packet[TCP].decode_payload_as(NBTSession)`

And then you Will get the decoded layers by scapy:

```
 packet[TCP].show()


[ TCP ]
 sport     = microsoft_ds
```

…

```
 options   = []
[ NBT Session Packet ]### 
    TYPE      = Session Message
    RESERVED  = 0
    LENGTH    = 4873
[ SMBNegociate Protocol Request Header ]### 
       Start     = '\xfeSMB'
       Command   = 64
       Error_Class= 0
       Reserved  = 1
       Error_code= 0
       Flags     = 0
       Flags2    = 0
       PIDHigh   = 5
       Signature = 0
       Unused    = 0
       TID       = 183
       PID       = 0
       UID       = 0
       MID       = 0
       WordCount = 0
       ByteCount = 0
[ SMB Negotiate Protocol Request Tail ]###
BufferFormat= 0
          BufferData= '\x03'
```

Also you can try after that to decode the packet with the different clases:

```
packet.decode_payload_as(SMBNegociate Protocol Request Header)
```

Comment: A better answer would be to bind the TCP port you are using to the SMB packet yourself. Scapy does not register all possible ports by default. See `bind_layers`

Comment: @Cukic0d do you mean something like this?
 `bind_layers(TCP, smb, sport=445)
  bind_layers(TCP, smb, dport=445)`
I get and Error
` AttributeError: module 'scapy.layers.smb' has no attribute '_overload_fields' `

Comment: It's not going to be "smb" but a real packet. Because SMB upper layer is netbios have a look at the scapy/layers/netbios.py file in scapy's source code. You just have to mimic the bindings at the bottom for your own protocol